# Incomplete man page for echo on OSX 10.10.3?

Tags: echo, osx-yosemite, manpage

When I run:

```
$ man echo
```

Does not display any information regarding the flag "-e" on OSX 10.10.3, however clearly that flag exists:

```
$ echo "\xFF" > hex
$ cat hex
\xFF
$ echo -e "\xFF" > hex
$ cat hex
?
```

Can anyone explain this ? Can the man pages ever be incomplete?